# Sending GA dimension without including a pageview

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

From what I understand, setting a dimension:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'value');
```

requires sending the dimension afterwards using:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

My problem is that the header file with all my ga codes (including send pageview) loads before the file where I have my dimension. So if I send it again, won't I get two pageviews registered? Is there a way to do an empty send with ga and just send whatever has been set before it, nothing more?

Comment: Yes you are probably going to get two.  A hit type is required wither it be 'pageview', 'screenview', 'event', 'transaction', 'item', 'social', 'exception', 'timing'  is up to you.     Might want to figure out why its loading first and fix that part.

Comment: Seems to be the only solution for now. Guess I'll do that. Thanks!