# GA track author after pageview was already sent

Tags: google-analytics

can add a author tracking to GA, after the pageview was already sent? As I understand I cannot add custom dimension as it is a part of a pageview.

Can I add author as event in the footer and send event and track author views with it?

Answer (score 0):

This is broadly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544246/sending-ga-dimension-without-including-a-pageview). Yes, you need an interaction hit to send custom dimensions (read the comment to the linked question), and that may be an event as well as a pageview.

However for your case the result might not be what you are aiming for. "Author" sounds like a hit scoped dimension. Hit scope (and product scope as a special case of hit scope) are set per interaction hit (session scope retains only the last value set in a session. User scope refers to a value retained over multiple sessions). If you track the author I think you really want the author name connected to the page url, not an event. It depends a bit on your reporting requirements, but IMO it would be far better to associate the author dimension with the pageview (e.g. it would be much easier to break down the author by articles viewed). So that's something to keep in mind.

Comment: But the main requirement for me is to send information about the author after the pageview was already sent. Actually the information I need is the overall author views, not per article views. I just never worked with events in GA, so thats why I'm asking if the event would count what I need.